# Descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int', but it is a date?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to get the current year in my python code. And for some reason I am getting the following error

> descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a
>   'int'

But if I print the data type it says it is a date....

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date

def month_list(request):
    today = datetime.now()
    print today
    print type(today)
    year = today.year
    month_list = []
    for i in range(1, 13):
        month_list.append((i, datetime.date(year, i, 1).strftime('%B')))
    print month_list
    return render(request, "app/template.html")
```

And in the console

```
2017-06-09 08:53:18.852041
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
Internal Server Error: /app/month_list/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Database/project/app/views.py", line 468, in month_list
    month_list.append((i, datetime.date(year, i, 1).strftime('%B')))
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

I've used the same lines of code in another view and it works fine... guess I've done something stupid here...?

Thanks

Comment: Try in this way : datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: What line trows the exception? Where are you using the date? Are you using `today` or `year`?

Comment: Can't reproduce your result, are you sure the error isn't caused by part of the code you omitted?

Comment: I've added the traceback... :) @tobias_k using the year I've added more code

Comment: What exactly is `month_list.append`…? In your code `month_list` should be a function, so that part makes little sense at all.

Comment: missed month_list = [] whoops @deceze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be `month_list.append((i, date(year, i, 1).strftime('%B')))`

Since you imported date from the datetime module already, you can just refer to it directly.

Comment: @deceze thanks and edited! still new to answering questions here

Comment: @Ruth Fuller explanation: your `datetime.date` referred to `datetime.datetime.date`, i.e. the `date` method of a `datetime` object, which is defined as `def date(self)`, where `self` needs to be a `datetime` instance.